# Google Map API Marker Icon Url?

Tags: google-maps, url, google-maps-api-3, icons, marker

I'm trying to change marker icon to "red-circle" or "red-pin" or anything else.
In these codes;

```
markerOptions: {
      icon: 'images/beachflag.png'
    },
```

the marker doesn't show. But if i make the `icon` line a comment line, so marker shows like *"`red-pin`"*  icon

So, i need to marker icons list or URL list which directly supported by Google Map API. Or is there such a thing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is the (unofficial) list that I refer to:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/Google-Maps-API/2k3T5hwI5Ck/RRso0D2jB1oJ

provided by pamela (who was a Google employee at the time), it is fairly old, but still accurate.

=================== -- ============================

```
-- from Mike Williams --

It's also worth noting that only the original set of icons is available
in the location that was mentioned earlier in this thread

E.g. blue.png is available at both locations
  http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png
  http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png
But the new yen.png icon is only here
  http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/yen.png

-- from pamela --

I'll provide the list to you here, but you should know it's possible
some of these icons will disappear later. You may want to copy to your
own server to be sure.
Happy reading... :)
POI.png
POI.shadow.png
arts.png
arts.shadow.png
bar.png
bar.shadow.png
blue-dot.png
blue-pushpin.png
blue.png
bus.png
bus.shadow.png
cabs.png
cabs.shadow.png
camera.png
camera.shadow.png
campfire.png
campfire.shadow.png
campground.png
campground.shadow.png
caution.png
caution.shadow.png
coffeehouse.png
coffeehouse.shadow.png
convienancestore.png
convienancestore.shadow.png
cycling.png
cycling.shadow.png
dollar.png
dollar.shadow.png
drinking_water.png
drinking_water.shadow.png
earthquake.png
earthquake.shadow.png
electronics.png
electronics.shadow.png
euro.png
euro.shadow.png
fallingrocks.png
fallingrocks.shadow.png
ferry.png
ferry.shadow.png
firedept.png
firedept.shadow.png
fishing.png
fishing.shadow.png
flag.png
flag.shadow.png
gas.png
gas.shadow.png
golfer.png
golfer.shadow.png
green-dot.png
green.png
grn-pushpin.png
grocerystore.png
grocerystore.shadow.png
groecerystore.png
groecerystore.shadow.png
helicopter.png
helicopter.shadow.png
hiker.png
hiker.shadow.png
homegardenbusiness.png
homegardenbusiness.shadow.png
horsebackriding.png
horsebackriding.shadow.png
hospitals.png
hospitals.shadow.png
hotsprings.png
hotsprings.shadow.png
info.png
info.shadow.png
info_circle.png
info_circle.shadow.png
landmarks-jp.png
landmarks-jp.shadow.png
lightblue.png
lodging.png
lodging.shadow.png
ltblu-pushpin.png
ltblue-dot.png
man.png
man.shadow.png
marina.png
marina.shadow.png
mechanic.png
mechanic.shadow.png
motorcycling.png
motorcycling.shadow.png
movies.png
movies.shadow.png
msmarker.shadow.png
orange-dot.png
orange.png
parkinglot.png
parkinglot.shadow.png
partly_cloudy.png
partly_cloudy.shadow.png
pharmacy-us.png
pharmacy-us.shadow.png
phone.png
phone.shadow.png
picnic.png
picnic.shadow.png
pink-dot.png
pink-pushpin.png
pink.png
plane.png
plane.shadow.png
police.png
police.shadow.png
postoffice-jp.png
postoffice-jp.shadow.png
postoffice-us.png
postoffice-us.shadow.png
purple-dot.png
purple-pushpin.png
purple.png
pushpin_shadow.png
question.png
question.shadow.png
rail.png
rail.shadow.png
rainy.png
rainy.shadow.png
rangerstation.png
rangerstation.shadow.png
realestate.png
realestate.shadow.png
recycle.png
recycle.shadow.png
red-dot.png
red-pushpin.png
red.png
restaurant.png
restaurant.shadow.png
sailing.png
sailing.shadow.png
salon.png
salon.shadow.png
shopping.png
shopping.shadow.png
ski.png
ski.shadow.png
snack_bar.png
snack_bar.shadow.png
snowflake_simple.png
snowflake_simple.shadow.png
sportvenue.png
sportvenue.shadow.png
subway.png
subway.shadow.png
sunny.png
sunny.shadow.png
swimming.png
swimming.shadow.png
toilets.png
toilets.shadow.png
trail.png
trail.shadow.png
tram.png
tram.shadow.png
tree.png
tree.shadow.png
truck.png
truck.shadow.png
volcano.png
volcano.shadow.png
water.png
water.shadow.png
waterfalls.png
waterfalls.shadow.png
webcam.png
webcam.shadow.png
wheel_chair_accessible.png
wheel_chair_accessible.shadow.png
woman.png
woman.shadow.png
yellow-dot.png
yellow.png
yen.png
yen.shadow.png
ylw-pushpin.png
```